# Question on Popover

Tags: cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller, ipad

In my app I have a navigation back button which occupies the top left of the navigation bar as such. Now I have a requirement to make the view in the navigation stack a split view. I'm doing my own custom split view controller. Now the question arises in the portrait mode of this split view. I want it to have the default popover behavior in portrait mode (like Apple's splitview in portrait). Can I manually set the location for the popover button on the navigation bar to some place other than top left without violating any UI guidelines? Since the back button is on top left corner by default already. I read over the UI guidelines but could not find anything concrete relating to this issue. Can the popover button be placed anywhere on the navigation bar for the portrait mode of my custom split view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. As you said, there is no strict rule over placement of the pop-over in portrait mode.

[This app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ndtv-hd/id390847563?mt=8) uses custom split view and the placement of the button to display the navigator (inside a popover) in portrait mode varies on what view controller it is currently displaying. Whether it is the root of the navigation or if it is the view controller pushed over the navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question should've been more like whether I can place a Navigation back button on the top left corner of the navigation bar and also place the popover button right next to this back button on the same navigation bar (popover button is for the portrait splitview). Maybe I misunderstood your reply.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant too! If you see the app you will get to know.